# conversion of date string 12 hours and 24 hours format getting wrong values

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a date string 
 NSString *strDate=@"12 March 2015 07:20:57 pm";
which I am getting from server

For 24 hours device format getting wrong value

> 03/12/2015 12:20:57

Which should have been

> 03/12/2015 19:20:57

My code is Here

```
-(NSString *)changeformate_string24hr:(NSString *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [df setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

    NSDate* wakeTime = [df dateFromString:date];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];


    return [df stringFromDate:wakeTime];

}
```

Please let me know where is my problem and help me to get out from this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using *two* date formatters, one for input and one for output?  Also, to improve performance, you should probably be allocating and configuring the data formatters only once.

Answer (score 1):

Correct input format should be

```
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Difference between `HH` and `hh` is described [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: This answer is correct, but doesn't explain what you are seeing. Non-exhaustive testing suggests that if "HH" and "a" are combined in a format, which makes the format invalid, rather than producing an error `NSDateFormatter` returns 0 for the hour if AM is present and 12 for the hour if PM is present, the actual hour value itself being ignored. So unless this is documented somewhere it looks like you've stumbled on a feature/bug.

Comment: Hi ,
can you please help me convert a nsstring of 2 April 2015 13:35:54 19800 to a Nsdate.

Comment: Please help me I am getting an value of  2015-04-22 10:43:57 NSString but getting problem when converting into NSSdate.Plz help me convert the same into Nsdate into same format given in NSString. Here is my code
NSString *getString=@"2015-04-22 10:43:57";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
     NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:getString];